# How to install Ubuntu touch on X86 tablet with windows 8?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, windows-8

have a tablet X86 with architecture pc of Colombian brand PC Smart, currently has Windows 8.1 more bing, have managed to enter the menu of the BIOS, but I'm bored of Windows is malisimo damaged by anything and it gets slow with the pass time, well I want to install Ubuntu Touch on the tablet, not ubuntu desktop but Ubuntu touch, but Windows 8, the method to install a zip file does not work and the other method with a computer with Ubuntu does not work because it is not Android PC architecture is, but as I install Ubuntu x86 touch on this tablet with Windows 8.1 more Bing! It has a great ability so I think the system would endure perfect but as I do to install it without the android method or the zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Ubuntu touch x86 for tablet has not been released yet. When it is, it will be based on the all-new non-LTS Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak, which will be released next month (October).

<sup>The Preinstalled Touch Image allows you to install a preinstalled preview of Ubuntu Touch onto a target device.</sup>
 <sup>• [Ubuntu Touch 16.10 (Yakkety Yak) Daily Build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/)</sup>

Comment: M.m can not wait that long, my tablet is useless!
You know if you can convert the desktop to tablet? or install a graphic tablet desktop environment in Ubuntu? because I searching the internet I found an archive with booksellers and parcel of Ubuntu Touch, but is not an installer, it is like a structure to put on an existing platform!

Comment: the platform is because of the CPU. You would need to change your CPU to do that.